# Prove or disprove the inequality that generalized the base cases

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have come across with a question that say prove or disprove the following:

$$\frac{(n_{1}+n_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot n_{m})(n_{1}+n_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot n_{m}-1)\cdot \cdot \cdot (n_{1}+n_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot n_{m}-(m-1))}{m!}\leq \frac{(n_{1}+n_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot+n_{m})^{m}}{m^{m-1}}$$

Where all $n_i$ are positive integers.

For $m=1$, I have the following:

$$n_1\leq n_1$$ which is true.

For $m=2$, I have the following:

$$\frac{(n_1+n_2)(n_1+n_2-1)}{2!}\leq \frac{(n_1+n_2)^2}{2}$$

Which is again true.

For $m=3$, I have the following:

$$\frac{(n_1+n_2+n_3)(n_1+n_2+n_3-1)(n_1+n_2+n_3-2)}{3!}\leq \frac{(n_1+n_2+n_3)^3}{9}$$

This intuitively seems to be true as, if I take, $n_1=n_2=n_3=1$ the inequality hold good. Since the denominator in both the inequalities is fixed and $(n_1+n_2+n_3)(n_1+n_2+n_3-1)(n_1+n_2+n_3-2)\leq (n_1+n_2+n_3)^3$, so I think this inequlity should hold, am I missing somthing? If not then same technique will work for general inequlity as well.

Any hints, suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: Are the $n_k$ positive integers, or something else?

Comment: @saulspatz, yes $n_k$ are positive integers.

Comment: Please add this information to the body of the question.

Comment: @saulspatz, added thank you.

Comment: The $n_k$ don't really play any role, I think.  The question can be restated as if $x\geq m$ then $$\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-m+1)}{m!}\leq\frac{x^m}{m^{m-1}}$$ Here $x$ and $m$ are positive integers, but if it's true, it's probably true for $x$ real.  (I should have said, $x=n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m$.)

Comment: @saulspatz, that is great!

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a comment, if we let $x=n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_m$, then the statement becomes $$\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-m+1)}{m!}\leq\frac{x^m}{m^{m-1}}$$which we can rewrite as $$
\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(1-\frac kx\right)\leq \frac{m!}{m^{m-1}}$$ or
$$\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(m-\frac {mk}x\right)\leq m!\tag1$$  If we let $x\to\infty$ in $(1)$, we get $$m^{m-1}\leq m!$$ which is false for $m>2$.

So, while your proof in the $m=2$ case is correct, the  statement is false for $m>2$.  If we choose the $n_k$ large enough, we can find a counterexample.

Comment: @Manojupreti Erf.  I must still be asleep.  Thanks.

Comment: The edit that I made, and have since deleted, was also wrong.  I must have my head on backwards today.